# Automatic question title search fail

Tags: feature-request

I just saw the question [Where does “Hello, World!” come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798620/where-does-hello-world-come-from-closed), which is an exact duplicate of [Where does ‘Hello world’ come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602237/where-does-hello-world-come-from), right down to the exact words in the title. Curious, I entered the first text into the ask-a-question box, and instead of suggesting the second post, it just said that wasn't a very good title:

[image]

without suggesting the obvious exact duplicate question.

I would suggest that even if (perhaps *especially if*) the title doesn't have any good words in it, that the automatic question search still populate the suggested question list with whatever comes up in the search?

Answer (score 2):

I can see why you wouldn't want to do that as the "error" message thus gets ignored; it's lost in the wash of the suggested question results.  A better solution might be to hide the editor until the user affirmatively clicks a "I want to ask this anyway" button, then populate the suggested questions and show the editor.

Comment: This "I want to ask this anyway" button should only be available to users with a reputation above a certain threshold.

Comment: ...which leads back to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30543/how-can-so-improve-the-automatic-pre-question-search

Comment: @eleven81 - not likely to happen as it presents too big a barrier to entry to users who end up at SO from google and want to ask a question.

Comment: Could the error be moved above the text box, thus making room for the suggested questions list? (And be made bold, red and play a klaxon sound so the user has at least a 3.2% chance of reading it?)

Comment: Remove the "ask anyway" button, no matter how much rep the asker has. Then we do not have the duplicate. One poor question down...

Comment: @John Smithers --  the "not a good title" message has nothing to do with whether it's a duplicate or not.  It's only some algorithm's opinion of the language you use.

Comment: I know that, tvanfosson. But I like the "kill two flies with one stroke" approach.